# Express $\Bbb{R}$ as a sum of two disjoint subsets

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, group-theory

Consider the additive group of real numbers $(\Bbb{R},+)$.
Does there exist any mutually disjoint nonempty subsets $A,B$ of $\Bbb{R}$ such that $$\Bbb{R}=A+B$$
In another word, for every real number $r$, 
$$r=a+b$$
for $a\in A$ and $b\in B$.

I do a lot of trial and error but still cannot construct such pair of subsets.
So far the fact that I have is if such pair of subsets exist, at least one of the set must contain both rational and irrational numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about $A=[0,\infty)$ and $B=(-\infty,0)$? Surely every real number is the sum of a positive number and a negative number.

Comment: I guess both of our solutions had a flaw.

Comment: What flaw?  $7 = 8 + (-1) \in A+B$.

Comment: @PrudiiArca $0=1+(-1)$

Comment: Jap. I noticed and am overly embarrassed now -.-

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Kavi Rama Murthy's idea.

The sets I construct will be $A=(0,\infty)$ and $B=(-\infty,0]$.

For every real number $r$,
Case 1: $r>0$. Then $r=r+0\in A+B$.
Case 2: $r=0$. Then $r=1+(-1)\in A+B$.
Case 3: $r<0$. Then $r=1+(r-1)\in A+B$.